# How do I check and insert into a borrowed Hashmap in the same function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am new to Rust. I have implemented a hashmap to cache objects from a database. I have a function to locate the object which checks the hashmap and if it is not there then retrieves from the database and inserts into the hashmap for future use. I want the locate function to return a reference to the object in the hashmap so it can be used. Here is an example of the issue using fruit:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut fruit: HashMap<u16, String> = HashMap::new();

    fruit.insert(1, String::from("apple"));
    fruit.insert(7, String::from("banana"));
    fruit.insert(13, String::from("cherry"));

    println!("Fruit 7 is {}", locate_fruit(&mut fruit, 7).unwrap());
    println!("Fruit 15 is {}", locate_fruit(&mut fruit, 15).unwrap());
}

fn locate_fruit(fruit: &mut HashMap<u16, String>, fruit_id: u16) -> Option<&String> {

    if let Some(fruit_name) = fruit.get(&fruit_id) {
        return Some(fruit_name);
    }

    // in real code, get new_fruit from database
    let new_fruit = String::from("new fruit");

    fruit.insert(fruit_id, new_fruit);

    fruit.get(&fruit_id)
}
```

The compiler complains: `cannot borrow '*fruit' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable` for the `fruit.insert` line because I cannot create a mutable reference once I already have a immutable one. I have tried using a lifetime annotation as follows:

```
fn locate_fruit<'a>(fruit: &'a mut HashMap<u16, String>, fruit_id: u16) -> Option<&'a String>
```

but this does not resolve the issue. I need to somehow tell the compiler that it can drop the reference that is made in the first `fruit.get()` call. Any help appreciated!

(Also do I need to call `fruit.get()` again at the end, or can I somehow pass the reference to `new_fruit` back? e.g. `Some(&new_fruit)`)

Comment: Use the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API.

Comment: @MatthieuM. [Huh?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c2888711ffa8182d134ba34e14466341)

Comment: @Jmb here the case is a bit more complicated because (I assume) the generation of the value to insert is failible so there needs to be a path for `String::from` to fail, which `or_insert_with` doesn't provide. [Not too hard to desugar though](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=393eab9c2e6e3b36ebb606951d083acc).

Comment: @Jmb: I misread the OP's issue in the first place, nevermind ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred way is to just check if the map contains the value first and if not, insert it. This is mostly just because it feels more intuitive. It also does not require an owned version of the map key like `.entry(x)` does.

```rust
fn locate_fruit(fruit: &mut HashMap<u16, String>, fruit_id: u16) -> Option<&String> {
    if !fruit.contains_key(&fruit_id) {
        fruit.insert(fruit_id, String::from("new fruit"));
    }

    fruit.get(&fruit_id)
}
```

However you can get better performance by getting the entry and filling it if it does not yet exist. This approach uses a closure so the value to insert is only created if it is needed. Alternatively, `.or_insert(String::from("new fruit"))` could also be used, but it would allocate (and likely immediately free) a new string every call.

```rust
fn locate_fruit(fruit: &mut HashMap<u16, String>, fruit_id: u16) -> &str {
    fruit.entry(fruit_id).or_insert_with(||String::from("new fruit"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sweet and simple. For the entry/closure solution you mean something like:     `fruit.entry(fruit_id).or_insert_with(||{String::from("new fruit")});`? (which works nicely).